# Append the same value to two or more arrays

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to append the same value to two different arrays in one statement? For e.g.,

```
a = [], b = [] 
a,b << 10
```

Comment: The code `a = [], b = []` likely don't behave as you would expect: `a == [[],[]] && b == []`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [1,2]; b = [3]

a,b = [a, b].product([10]).map(&:flatten)
```

or

```
a,b = [a,b].zip(Array.new(2,10)).map(&:flatten)
```

or

```
a,b = [a,b].zip([10]*2).map(&:flatten)
```

# => `a = [1, 2, 10]`, `b = [3, 10]`

This obviously generalizes to any number of arrays.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep different arrays then I think the only possibility is to do this:

```
a, b = a << 10, b << 10
```

Obviously, it does not fulfill the requirement to write the value just once. With the comma it is possible to write values in an array notation. On the left side of the assignment are two values which can consume an array up to length two.

What is on the right side of the assignment? There are two values written in array notation. After evaluation you could write:

```
a, b = [[a], [b]]

# a <- [a]
# b <- [b]
```

Alternatively, if you are fine with semicolon:

```
a << 10; b << 10;
```

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to `a << 10; b << 10`?

Comment: The semicolon version is IMHO the best one.

Comment: `value = 10; a << value; b << value` ;-) It is just that some people have an aversion for using semicolon in Ruby. Above all, it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @Stefan Strictly speaking using the semicolon, you end having two statements, not one as OP is asking.

Comment: @toro2k, I believe that's @Stefan's point, but I'd side with 
platzhirsch because parallel assignment is not sugar for a pair of assignments (e.g., `x, y = y, x`).

Answer (score 4):

I would do this:

```
[a,b].each { |arr| arr.push( 10 ) }
```

Comment: NB: I think that clever use of Ruby's parsing of assignment, comma etc operators to fit in less characters will backfire when it comes to maintain the code (not part of my answer though, more suited to codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: The most rubiest way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

How is this using [***`initialize_copy`***](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/initialize_copy):

```
a=[]
b=[]
a.object_id # => 11512248
b.object_id # => 11512068

b.send(:initialize_copy,a << 10)
a # => [10]
b # => [10]
a.object_id # => 11512248
b.object_id # => 11512068
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

```
a,b = [],[]
c = 10

a,b = a.push(c),b.push(c)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do like this

```
a = b << 10
p a.inspect
p b.inspect
```

Hope it resolve your issue

Comment: Check `a.__id__` and `b.__id__`.

Comment: Everything seems ok, I don't agree your comment. see this voted post result a, b = a << 10, b << 10 a.__id__ and b.__id__

I raised concern on about your comments

Comment: Your previous comment misleading... you just commenting without explaining anything.

Comment: @Veerasekar you're assigning `b` to `a`. If you would start with `a = [:a]` and `b = [:b]` your code would not result in `[:a,10]` and `[:b,10`] but in `[:a,10]` and `[:a,10`], i.e. the same array for both, `a` and `b`.